# Flutter main.dart code on IntelliJ IDEA stuck on "syncing files to device ..."

Tags: firebase, flutter, intellij-idea

My code uses firestore data. I'm using IOS Simulator, which shows a white screen with the loading circle symbol while running the code. I have tried the following:

- adding `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` to main.dart
- changing channel from flutter stable to flutter beta
- invalidating caches/restarting

This is what the console says currently:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on testiphone in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           38.1s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55015/FLL78hIxJWU=/ws
Syncing files to device testiphone...
```

Can someone please help figure out a solution? Have spent the last 2 days trying to fix this myself/by scouring forums for advice.